# Finding out a limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x - e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}$

Tags: analysis, limits, trigonometry, exponential-function

I have trouble finding $$\large \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x - e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}.$$ I can use L'Hospital's rule, but it seems slightly ineffective there. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Most of the times I prefer Taylor to LHR except in some cases where I have no choice (like $x\ln x$ as $x\to 0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that, as $x \to 0$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\cos x &=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\\\\
e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}&=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)
\end{align}
$$ then
$$
\frac{\cos x - e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}=\frac{\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)}{x^4}=-\frac{1}{12}+\mathcal{O}(x^2)
$$ giving the desired limit.

Answer (score 2):

The consecutive derivatives of numerator/denominator are

$$\begin{align}&(1)\;\;\frac{-\sin x+xe^{-x^2/2}}{4x^3}\\{}\\
&(2)\;\;\frac{-\cos x+e^{-x^2/2}-x^2e^{-x^2/2}}{12x^2}\\{}\\
&(3)\;\;\frac{\sin x-3xe^{-x^2/2}+x^3e^{-x^2/2}}{24x}\\{}\\
&(4)\;\;\frac{\cos x-3e^{-x^2/2}+6x^2e^{-x^2/2}-x^4e^{-x^2/2}}{24}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\frac{1-3}{24}=-\frac1{12}\end{align}$$

Not that terrible, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor at order $4$:

- $\cos x=1-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)$
- $\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{x^2}2}=1- \dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)$

Hence $$\frac{\cos x - e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}=\frac{\cfrac{x^4}{24}-\dfrac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)}{x^4}=\frac1{24}-\frac{1}{8}+o(1)=-\frac{1}{12}+o(1).$$

Thus $\,\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\cos x - e^{- \tfrac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}=-\dfrac 1{12}.$

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply L'Hopitals rule four times to get a result that way. It is probably quicker to use a series expansion on the numerator. You will need to take the series to at least the term in $x^4$ to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the following standard limits only:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos x-1+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{4}} &=&\frac{1}{24}
\\
&& \\
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-u-e^{-u}}{u^{2}} &=&-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Re-write the original expression as
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\cos x-e^{-x^{2}/2}}{x^{4}}=\left( \frac{\cos x-1+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{%
x^{4}}\right) +\frac{1}{\left( \sqrt{2}\right) ^{4}}\cdot \left( \frac{%
1-\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) ^{2}-e^{-\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
^{2}}}{\left( \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) ^{2}\right) ^{2}}\right) 
\end{equation*}
Since
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) ^{2}=0,
\end{equation*}
then, substitute  $u=\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) ^{2}$ in the second
limit, one gets
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos x-e^{-x^{2}/2}}{x^{4}} &=&\lim_{x\rightarrow
0}\frac{\cos x-1+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{4}}+\frac{1}{\left( \sqrt{2}\right)
^{4}}\cdot \lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1-u-e^{-u}}{u^{2}}\right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{\left( \sqrt{2}\right) ^{4}}\left( -\frac{1}{2}%
\right)  \\
&=&-\frac{1}{12}.
\end{eqnarray*}