# Calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \cos x-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How do i calculate this limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \cos x-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{x^4}$$

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x - e^{- x^2/2}}{x^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1161547/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%5Cfrac%7B%20%5Ccos%20x-e%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7D%7Bx%5E4%7D%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the Taylor serie:

\begin{equation}
\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x^4)\\e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)
\end{equation}

we get:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \cos x-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x^4)-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)\right)}{x^4}=\\=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{12}x^4+o(x^4)}{x^4}=-\frac{1}{12}
\end{equation}

Comment: I get $-\frac{1}{12}$ also but by a simpler method.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Applying twice de l'Hopital theorem I suppose...:-)

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

As shown in answers, Taylor series are a fantastic tool for computing limits. But they can do much more.

In this specific case, continue adding terms for $\cos(x)$ and $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$; you would arrive to $$\frac{\cos (x)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}=-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{7 x^2}{360}-\frac{13 x^4}{5040}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ which, for sure, shows the limit but also how it is approached.

If you plot both functions for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ on the same graph, you will not be able to see the difference.